# Change Magento bundle product price type via database

Tags: mysql, database, magento, bundle

Is it possible to change an existing bundle product from dynamic to fixed price via the database rather than having to create a new product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mean using raw SQL queries. Anyway you can do this using magento Models. These steps should do the job for you (although I did not test it myself!):

Load your product:

```
    $bundleProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();      
    $bundleProduct->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);
```

Set the price type to 1:

```
    $bundleProduct->setPriceType(1); // Price types => 0: dynamic, 1: fixed
```

Save your product:

```
    $bundleProduct->save();
```

[Here](http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-bundle-products-in-magento/) you can find all the attributes that you can change programmatically for a bundle product.

---

```
    require_once ("app/Mage.php"); //Pass the exact path to Mage.php file here (e.g. the indicated path works if your script is under main magento installation folder)

    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $bundleProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();      
    $bundleProduct->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID); //Pass your bundle product ID here; you can get the ID from Magento admin panel
    $bundleProduct->setPriceType(1); // Price types => 0: dynamic, 1: fixed
    $bundleProduct->save();
```

Alternatively if you want to change this for all your exisiting bundle products use this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('type')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'bundle'));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setPriceType(1);
    $product->save;
}
```

You can whether run your script using php command  from command line or other methods (browser, wget, ..)

Comment: @Hugh You should create a PHP script that does that for you. I will add more detail to my answer soon to help you with that.